# How to disable VirtualKeyboard?

Tags: qt, qml, qtvirtualkeyboard

I tried the VirtualKeyboard basic sample https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-basic-example.html.
I want to understand how the VirtualKeyboard been enabled after TextField gets focused, to find out a way to disable VirtualKeyboard. Just normal Windows IME, the VirtualKeyboard can be enabled or disabled using the real keyboard.
Excepted behavior: when TextField gets focused, there is an option to decide to show the VirtualKeyboard or uses the original IME to input from the real keyboard.

Comment: From what I understand you want for example if there are 2 TextFields then when a TextField activates the virtualkeyboard when it gets the focus and the other does not, am I correct?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, and also if VKB is disabled, those items can use the OS IME to input lang Chinese or Japanese.

Comment: @eyllanesc I looking for an API like `VirtualKeyboard.enable = false` to disable the whole VKB function just like I didn't import it.

Comment: It's a way to write own onscreen keyboard base on: https://github.com/githubuser0xFFFF/QtFreeVirtualKeyboard Using your own keyboard you have full control when it's open (for which fields) or open it manually. For example, you can have two versions of keyboards (literal and numeric) and open one for special fields in your application.